# Mysql doesn't display right single quotation mark(’) after inserted into table

Tags: mysql, unicode, character

I have a table called "Testing". I inserted a row which contains `unicode` character right single quotation (**'**) **0x2019**  in name field.
SQL :

```
 //insert into Testing values(Sno,Name,Address)    
   insert into Testing values(1,"**Rajesh’s Friend**","Cumbum");
```

When listing the same row in `Mysql Query Browser` or `CommandLine`. It displays as a normal ANSI character(**'**) instead of being unicode character.

I want to display the same unicode character in `MySQL` table.

Comment: What collation is the table set to?  Can you provide the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE Testing; ?

Comment: I've often seen this and as it forms part of sql injection as long as you escape the string, it then works.

Comment: How doe you know if it is ascii?  ` SELECT HEX("’") 'utf8 quote', HEX("'") 'ascii quote';
+------------+-------------+
| utf8 quote | ascii quote |
+------------+-------------+
| E28099     | 27          |
+------------+-------------+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `ALTER TABLE Testing COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci';` to change the encoding.