# Right single quotation mark (Unicode:(U+2019) Extended Ascii 146) causes SQL injection through MySqlParameter

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, unicode, extended-ascii

I've run into a rather strange problem.

We have a MySql Database running behind our C#/Asp.Net web app.

We use parameters for each query in order to prevent SQL Injection attacks.

However we have recently being getting strange SQL Errors from a single customer.

On investigation we found that the customer had been pasting addresses containing the "Right single quotation mark" (’) character into fields on our site.

Surprisingly enough this seems to be getting through the parameterization section of our code, and getting inserted into the query, whereupon it was interpreted by our MySQL Server as an unescaped quotation mark.

This means that our customer is unknowingly performing an SQL injection attack on our server.

I have two questions regarding this:

1) Is this not incredibly insecure? If this worked against us are there other companies out there that may be subject to the same security vulnerability?

2) How do I fix this? Is there any way of sanitizing this input without running a regex or string replace before parameterizing user input? (With the size of the codebase and the amount of coders we have this could take up top a month of work).

We had always assumed that parameterization prevented anything less then concentrated malicious attack. Is this not the case?

Specs:
MySQLServer 5.6
MySql .Net Connector 1.0.10.0
Asp.Net 4.5.1

Any help or advice is appreciated...

Comment: Can you can manually reproduce this in a test case?

Comment: Yes, was able to reproduce on my local system. Was actually able to perform SQL injection using this character. Will need more time to see if I can do this on a fresh install of MySql.

Comment: Please provide a test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that SQL Server treats commands as unicode by default, so ASP.NET doesn't bother to clean up unicode characters, while your MySQL database is using ASCII.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387529/mysql-doesnt-display-right-single-quotation-mark-after-inserted-into-table), it should be possible to change your table to allow for the right single quote by using this command:

```
ALTER TABLE [Table] COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci';
```

From the MySQL documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-server.html), it looks like you can set the character set and collation mode for the entire server at runtime.  To test if it fixes your issue, try starting MySQL like this:

```
mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Hi Tim.Thanks for your response,  I think you might be correct in identifying the cause of this problem. However neither altering the character set of the affected table nor altering the character set of each column corrects the problem. The SQL server is still interpreting the Unicode character as an unescaped quotation mark. Is there a global database setting i might be missing that is causing this?  And if so, is there any concequence to having different character sets per database/table/columns?

Comment: Err...  I'm not sure how notifications work in terms of edits, but just in case you aren't notified, I've updated my answer to include code to set the character mode server-wide.  I don't believe there are any conflicts in having different character sets for different tables, but I'm not an expert in MySQL, so I will defer that to anyone who has more knowledge.